# Backing up redis at a specific time of day

Tags: redis

Is there any way to schedule redis back-ups at a specific time of day (e.g. 3:00 AM GMT) - preferably via a setting in the accompanying conf file?

I already understand that one can set a backup rule in redis configuration (e.g. save every X hours if Y keys have changed).

But how does one schedule the said backup at a particular time of day? Would love to know something basic, but effective. In case it matters, my redis version is `5.0.3`

Comment: You can't do it from inside Redis, but `crontab` is your friend

Comment: I believe @ruhul has done just that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know it is currently not possible from inside redis. But its achievable  using `crontab`. Here is a short example:

create a backup script file:
**/tmp/backup.sh**

```
echo save | redis-cli >> /tmp/redis-backup.log
```

If using sockets, the above would be:

`echo save | redis-cli -s /var/run/redis.sock >> /tmp/redis-backup.log`

The socket location in your system may vary.

Next, give execute permission to the script:
`chmod +x /tmp/backup.sh`

Finally, make an entry in crontab: `crontab -e`

```
0 3 * * * /tmp/backup.sh
```

This will run `backup.sh` in exactly 3AM.

In case you want to disable redis saving setup in the conf (without restarting the redis instance), the best way is to log into `redis-cli` and issue `CONFIG SET save ""`. Double check that it worked via `CONFIG GET save`. Finally, don't forget to change the `save` settings in the relevant conf file as well. Lastly, it's wiser to use `bgsave` instead of `save` if tackling a redis instance in production.

For more, checkout these links:

1. [How To Back Up and Restore Your Redis Data](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-redis-data-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. [Cron Scheduler](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)
3. [How To Start/Stop/Restart Cron Service In Linux](http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-startstoprestart-cron-service-in-linux/)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in ruhul. Just to confirm, one would couple this solution with a `nosave` in the redis config file, correct? (i.e. turn of auto/periodic saving in redis config, and use a cron job to do it at night)

Comment: In short "Yes".

Comment: @HassanBaig, thanks for making this answer more appropriate. (y)